# Avoid clipping objects when looking at them close-up in the Scene view

Tags: unity, c#, 3d

I am making a game in Unity3D, but whenever I get about 5 meters close to an object, the camera acts like I am right by it and does not render part of the screen.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

This is really inconvenient - how can I stop the object from getting cut off like that?

Comment: Is there a near clipping parameter on Unity's camera?

Comment: Searching ["unity editor near plane" turns up some recommended approaches on Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/118735/near-plane-adjustment-in-scene-view.html)

Comment: I do not know. I do not see any settings related to it.

Comment: Nevermind, I have figured out that you can press f on the object and it will zoom in on the object and fixed it. Please create an answer so I can accept the answer.